# Adding new thumbnails to dropzone.js after initialization

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have a web page that uses dropzone.js. My web page lets people choose their profile picture. If they have already set it, I want to show their picture, but allow them to change it. In an attempt to do this, I'm using the following dropzone code:

```
var currentPicture = null;
function removeCurrentPicture() {
  try {
    if (dropzone) {
      for (var i = 1; i < dropzone.files.length; i++) {
        dropzone.removeFile(dropzone.files[i-1]);
      }
    }
  } catch (ex1) {
    console.log(ex1);
  }

  return false;
}

function setThumbnailWidths() {
  var thumbnails = $("*[data-dz-thumbnail]");
  for (var i=0; i<thumbnails.length; i++) {
    $(thumbnails[i]).css('max-width', '150px');
  }
}


var pictureDropZone = new Dropzone("#myPicture", {
  url: "/profile/picture/",
  maxFilesize: 5,
  clickable: true,
  uploadMultiple: false,
  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
  previewsContainer: "#previews",
  init: function () {
    dropzone = this;

    // add picture if it exists
    var pictureUrl = 'DYNAMICALLY POPULATED FROM SERVER';
    if (pictureUrl) {
      var pictureSize = // POPULATED FROM SERVER;
      var pictureFileName = // POPULATED FROM SERVER;
      var pictureMimeType = 'img/png';

      var currentPicture = { name: pictureFileName, size: pictureSize, type: pictureMimeType };
      this.addFile.call(this, currentPicture);
      this.options.thumbnail.call(this, currentPicture, pictureUrl);
      this.files.push(currentPicture);

      $('#picturePrompt').hide();
    }

     this.on('addedfile', function (file) {
       if (dropzone.files.length > 1) {
         removeCurrentPicture();
       }

       $('#picturePrompt').hide();
       $("#errorMessage").hide();
     });

     this.on('removedfile', function (file) {
       $('#picturePrompt').show();
     });

     this.on('success', function (file, res) {
       setThumbnailWidths();
     });

     this.on('error', function (e, m) {
       $("#previews").hide();
       $("#errorMessage").html('An unknown error has happened. Please try again.');
       $("#errorMessage").show();
     });
   }
 });
```

The HTML that complements this dropzone looks like this:

```
<div id="myPicture" style="padding:40px; cursor:pointer;">
  <div id="picturePrompt">Drop a picture here or just click</div>
  <div id="errorMessage" class="error" style="display:none; margin-bottom:8px;"></div>

  <div class="files" id="previews">
    <div id="template" class="file-row">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li>
          <span class="preview" style="width:350px;"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
          <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
        </li>
        <li style="vertical-align:top;">
          <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top:8px;">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-left"></i>
            <span class="pull-left">Delete</span>
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code works unless a picture is loaded from the server when the page loads. In the event that `pictureUrl` is set, the picture renders fine. I can "delete" it. However, if I try to add a new picture, the new thumbnail does not appear. The size of the file does. But the thumbnail does not show.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try `myDropzone.createThumbnail(file)`?